# How to convert a swagger 1.1 spec to a swagger >= 1.2 spec

Tags: swagger, openapi

I'm trying to generate client code for C#/asp.net core to consume a service that has a swagger 1.1 specification. (The service is out of my control). Unfortunately most up-to-date tools require at a swagger 1.2 spec. Most tools even require open-api 2.0. Even most converters start at 1.2. Does anybody know a tool to upgrade from 1.1 to 1.2?

I'd even consider a manual rewrite, but I can't find anywhere what changed between 1.1 and 1.2

Answer (score 2):

First of all, 1.2 is also a very old version. Consider converting to OpenAPI 2.0 (used by most tools nowadays) or maybe even OpenAPI 3.0 (the latest version).

#### Swagger Codegen

[Swagger Codegen](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen) can generate client/server code from 1.x-3.0 specs, and can also convert Swagger 1.x to OpenAPI 2.0 or 3.0.

To generate a C# client from a Swagger 1.x spec using [Codegen CLI v. 2.x](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/io/swagger/swagger-codegen-cli/):

```
java -jar swagger-codegen-cli-2.4.0.jar generate
     -i http://path/to/spec.json
     -l csharp
     -o ./csharp-client
```

To convert Swagger 1.x to OpenAPI 2.0, Codegen CLI v. 2.x with the `-l swagger` argument to get JSON or `-l swagger-yaml` to get YAML.

```
java -jar swagger-codegen-cli-2.4.0.jar generate
     -i http://path/to/spec.json
     -l swagger
     -o ./converted
```

To convert to OpenAPI 3.0, use [Codegen CLI v. 3.x](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/io/swagger/codegen/v3/swagger-codegen-cli/) with the `-l openapi` argument to get JSON or `-l openapi-yaml` to get YAML.

```
java -jar swagger-codegen-cli-3.0.3.jar generate
     -i http://path/to/spec.json
     -l openapi
     -o ./converted
```

#### API Transformer

[API Transformer](https://www.apimatic.io/transformer) claims to support Swagger 1.x -> 1.2 / 2.0 / 3.0 conversion.

Comment: Sorry, I should've mentioned it. But I've tried the official codegen, both 3.0 and 2.0 branches. But it doesn't seem to understand the "responseClass" tag so it generates a client where all return types are void. :/. API Transformer is unable to locate all resources defined by the root swagger file because it can't send the required security parameters when accessing them. Uploading also doesn't work since I can only upload one file :/.

Comment: It could be a bug report in the Codegen's parser, consider filing a bug report at https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues/. I'm not aware of any other 1.x converters.